# Max of Second Derivative, Wrong answer apparently

Tags: calculus

I am given the integral: $\int_{0}^{4}5e^{-x^{2}}dx$. I am told to find the Error bound using the Midpoint rule, which is $\frac{K(b-a)^3}{24n^2}$. After finding the second derivative of the given formula, I used my calculator to find that the max of the second derivative is $4.4626032$. I have plugged in this answer into my webwork question, but it has marked it wrong for some reason, despite the fact that this is the only maximum point within the interval $[0,4]$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not using MathJax for one..

Answer (score 1):

Let $f (x)=5e^{-x^2} $.
then

$$f'(x)=-10xe^{-x^2} $$

$$f''(x)=(-10+20x^2)e^{-x^2} $$

$$f'''(x)=20x (3-2x^2)e^{-x^2} $$

$$\max_{0\le x\le 4} f''(x)=f''(\frac {\sqrt {3}}{\sqrt {2}}) $$
$$=20e^{-\frac {3}{2}} $$
$$\approx 4.4626$$

Comment: ^^ I got that exact same answer and put it into webwork, and it still marked it wrong, but that IS the max point of the 2nd derivative of the original function.

Comment: The question reads as is: "The value of K = max |f′′(x)| on the interval [0, 4] =..."

Comment: And the question states that N = 4

Comment: You and I are correct. What is the answer given ?

Comment: I'm not given the correct answer as this is an ongoing webwork assignment. I'm just trying to figure out where the error in my method of solving this question lies. The previous questions asked me to find the 2nd derivative of the original equation which I found to be the same one as you posted, but when solving for K, your answer is the same as mine, but webwork still marks it wrong for some strange reason.

Comment: The webwork is not as serious as MS exchange.